# Kernel keeps dying using jupyter (Anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

My kernel keeps dying but I have no idea what the problem is. I have reinstalled anaconda a couple of times but nothing is working. The error message is "can't import PY3." Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: It sounds like you may not have Python correctly installed, but there's not enough information here to tell.  Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling python as well, now only installing 3.6 (I have had python 2 before as well). I downloaded Anaconda again but it still does not work, but now I get another error message:

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Fia/anaconda/envs/python2/bin/python': '/Users/Fia/anaconda/envs/python2/bin/python'

Comment: Which is so strange because I downloaded anaconda for python 3 :(

Answer (score 0):

Run this-

```
conda remove ipykernel ipython jupyter_client jupyter_core traitlets ipython_genutils

    conda clean -tipsy

    conda install ipykernel ipython jupyter_client jupyter_core traitlets ipython_genutils

    jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

update numpy then try or remove ipykernel and then install it again then try.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code at the start of your script

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

It might have something to do with the kernel trying to import a module multiple times that it just crashes.